# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrap a bookie website for home, draw and away odds. I'm able to scrap off the first 10 values, however when it gets to index 11, `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element` error occurs. `n` in the for loop is used to dynamically fetch the next div in the website. I've also tried adding an implicit wait after `driver.get(url)` statement but it does not work.

**The Actual Error is:**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html[@class='no-js dark']/body/div[@class='app']/main/div[@class='mobile']/div[@class='mobile-router_view-container']/div[@class='contain-overflow']/div[@class='matches__container']/div[@class='matches']/div[@class='vue-pull-to-wrapper']/div[@class='scroll-container']/div[@class='prebet-match'][11]/div[@class='prebet-match__odd-market__container']/div[@class='prebet-match__teams']/span[@class='prebet-match__teams__home']"}
```

The **11** in the xpath is dynamic(**n**)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('headless')

PATH = "./chromedriver.exe"
url = 'https://www.betika.com/en-ke/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=option)

driver.get(url)


home_teams = []
away_teams = []
home_odds = []
draw = []
away_odds = []


for n in range(1,20):
    home_teams.append(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"/html[@class='no-js dark']/body/div[@class='app']/main/div[@class='mobile']/div[@class='mobile-router_view-container']/div[@class='contain-overflow']/div[@class='matches__container']/div[@class='matches']/div[@class='vue-pull-to-wrapper']/div[@class='scroll-container']/div[@class='prebet-match'][{n}]/div[@class='prebet-match__odd-market__container']/div[@class='prebet-match__teams']/span[@class='prebet-match__teams__home']").get_attribute('innerHTML'))
    away_teams.append(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"/html[@class='no-js dark']/body/div[@class='app']/main/div[@class='mobile']/div[@class='mobile-router_view-container']/div[@class='contain-overflow']/div[@class='matches__container']/div[@class='matches']/div[@class='vue-pull-to-wrapper']/div[@class='scroll-container']/div[@class='prebet-match'][{n}]/div[@class='prebet-match__odd-market__container']/div[@class='prebet-match__teams']/span[2]").get_attribute('innerHTML'))
    home_odds.append(float(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"/html[@class='no-js dark']/body/div[@class='app']/main/div[@class='mobile']/div[@class='mobile-router_view-container']/div[@class='contain-overflow']/div[@class='matches__container']/div[@class='matches']/div[@class='vue-pull-to-wrapper']/div[@class='scroll-container']/div[@class='prebet-match'][{n}]/div[@class='prebet-match__odd-market__container']/div[@class='prebet-match__odds__container']/div[@class='prebet-match__odds']/button[@class='prebet-match__odd'][1]/span[@class='prebet-match__odd__odd-value bold']").get_attribute('innerHTML')))
    draw.append(float(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"/html[@class='no-js dark']/body/div[@class='app']/main/div[@class='mobile']/div[@class='mobile-router_view-container']/div[@class='contain-overflow']/div[@class='matches__container']/div[@class='matches']/div[@class='vue-pull-to-wrapper']/div[@class='scroll-container']/div[@class='prebet-match'][{n}]/div[@class='prebet-match__odd-market__container']/div[@class='prebet-match__odds__container']/div[@class='prebet-match__odds']/button[@class='prebet-match__odd'][2]/span[@class='prebet-match__odd__odd-value bold']").get_attribute('innerHTML')))
    away_odds.append(float(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"/html[@class='no-js dark']/body/div[@class='app']/main/div[@class='mobile']/div[@class='mobile-router_view-container']/div[@class='contain-overflow']/div[@class='matches__container']/div[@class='matches']/div[@class='vue-pull-to-wrapper']/div[@class='scroll-container']/div[@class='prebet-match'][{n}]/div[@class='prebet-match__odd-market__container']/div[@class='prebet-match__odds__container']/div[@class='prebet-match__odds']/button[@class='prebet-match__odd'][3]/span[@class='prebet-match__odd__odd-value bold']").get_attribute('innerHTML')))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that some of your `xpaths` were invalid
I recommend `css selectors` as it is more clear and readable. You can also use tools like [`Selector Gadget`](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selectorgadget/mhjhnkcfbdhnjickkkdbjoemdmbfginb) to make it even easier
Loop through `div`s not numbers so it is easier:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()


url = 'https://www.betika.com/en-ke/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
driver.get(url)

home_teams = []
away_teams = []
home_odds = []
draw = []
away_odds = []

for i in range(5):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    sleep(2)
for row in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".prebet-match"):
    home_teams.append(row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".prebet-match__teams__home").get_attribute('innerHTML'))
    away_teams.append(row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.prebet-match__teams__home+ span').get_attribute('innerHTML'))
    home_odds.append(float(row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.prebet-match__odd:nth-child(1) .bold').get_attribute('innerHTML')))
    draw.append(float(row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.prebet-match__odd:nth-child(2) .bold').get_attribute('innerHTML')))
    away_odds.append(float(row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.prebet-match__odd:nth-child(3) .bold').get_attribute('innerHTML')))

print(home_teams, away_teams, home_odds, draw, away_odds,sep="\n")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: This one gets the first 10 values that are loaded on the page, I need to get more than 10

Comment: @Frosting updated with scroll.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of research I realized that site fetches only 10 values on loading and fetches more as you scroll, The 'Load more' button was not clickable so I had to change my approach. I decided to fetch the data directly from the API endpoint and change the limit i.e. (10) to any value I wanted.

**Here is the new code**

```
import http.client
import json

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.betika.com")

payload = ""

headers = {'cookie': "__cf_bm=IUdIW5DuTUklj090LYfwfKTblBGzb6VtPvukBIEx9Mw-1684241456-0-AcfDe74HLZ85Cs2OyRKH9OSNlUm9heyhUg3A41s%2Fl%2Fu%2FHWt0w7rZS1a4wVVnL73cP8kwcj8vxOHr3CMQTwamyZk%3D" }

conn.request("GET", "/v1/uo/matches?page=1&limit=200&tab=&sub_type_id=1%2C186%2C340&sport_id=14&tag_id=&sort_id=1&period_id=-1&esports=false", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

data = data.decode("utf-8")

print(data)
```

**conn.request** has a parameter limit which is currently set at 200, you can change that to get any number of values as long as the maximum limit is not exceeded.

For more information you can watch this video: [Web Scrapping using APIs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqtlR0y0suo)